# Calculation spreadsheet is empty

Tags: intershop

I'am actually working on the calculation spreadsheet (Cartridge dev_basketinfo, pipeline InspectBasket-Start).

It works well but when I got a specific shipping mode (on weightbased and specific postalcode) it is empty.

[image]

Do you know something about it please ?

Thanks

Comment: We have added specific prices in the spreadsheet. Maybe there is a problem the core and our CalculationView

Comment: It seems that our basket doesn't have a rulesetid when we retrieve it from GetBasketByID in bc_orderprocess.

But for other pipelet which fetch basket it got rulesetid so the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a method called on the fly which invalidate the basket.
If you see an empty spreadsheet be careful with the invalidation or the ruleset.